# Organizing an Integer Array in Ascending Order but with Ranges

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm given an Integer Array that goes: `{3,2,5,1,7,10,9,12,11,14,15,13,20}`. Now I need to sort it(already done this) and group the values that increase by 1 consecutively, i.e. convert `"1,2,3"` to `"1 to 3"`, in a "range".

With that the expected output from the array,

`{3,2,5,1,7,10,9,12,11,14,15,13,20}`

shoul be:

`"1 to 3, 5, 7, 9 to 15, 20"`

My solution so far is this:

```
//more code here
int[] a = new int[]{3,2,5,1,7,10,9,12,11,14,15,13,20};
String[] nSArr = new String[a.length];
String nStr = "";

for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    for(int j=i; j<a.length; j++) {
        if(a[j]==(a[i]+1)){
            nStr += Integer.toString(a[i])+","+Integer.toString(a[j])+" ";
        } else {
            nSArr[i] = a[i]+"";
        }
    }
}
//more code here
```

I'm planning on converting nStr into a String Array and using the duplicated numbers to connect consecutive numbers, but doing that seems to be wasteful. So my question is that, what better way should I store consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what better way should I store consecutive numbers?

You would be better off not storing them at all. If you have to produce a list of ranges, rather than printing it, you could create a `Range` class that has, for example, the initial number and the length of the run. Single-item runs would have length of one, which you could use in printing the result by returning `"7"` instead of `"7-7"`.

A common trick for grouping items this way is to construct a parallel array of `(value[i] - i)` numbers, like this:

```
Value:    1  2  3  5  7  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 20
Index:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
Diff:     1  1  1  2  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  8
```

All you need to do now is to group items with identical value of `Diff`. This can be done in a single pass, with the nested loop advancing the same loop counter as the outer loop for an O(n)-time solution. Moreover, you don't need to store `Diff` explicitly, so the solution would be O(1)-space:

```
int[] data = new int[] {3,2,5,1,7,10,9,12,11,14,15,13,20};
Arrays.sort(data);
int p = 0;
while (p != data.length) {
    System.out.print(data[p++]);
    int p0 = p;
    while (p != data.length && data[p-1]-(p-1) == data[p]-p) {
        p++;
    }
    if (p > p0+1) {
        System.out.print("-"+data[p-1]);
    } else {
        p = p0;
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/7lqD5t)

Comment: Your answer has been delivering so far but after some reading, a "range" can only be considered a "range" if it has three or more numbers in it. Your current answer considers a pair to be a range but as per definition it is not. I tried changing your code but I can't figure out what to do so, do thing you can help me one more time?

Comment: @Helquin Sure - the solution stores `p0`, and decides that a range is a "range" by comparing `p0` to `p` after the inner loop is over. You can make this check stricter, i.e. replace it with `if (p > p0+1)`, and then adding an `else` branch that moves `p` back to `p0` if the range is too short. See the edit.